CosmosDB calculated property to get age from date of birth
I'm looking for a way to get the age of a person given their date of birth in CosmosDB.
I've read on the docs that they've recently implemented "computed properties" at container level on this form:
{
  "computedProperties": [
    {
        "name": "cp_Age",
        "query": "SELECT VALUE DateTimeDiff('YYYY', c.DateOfBirth, GetCurrentDateTime()) FROM c"
    }
  ]
}

In my case, the DateOfBirth property is a DateOnly, so CosmosDB stores it's values as '2002-12-23'.
The code above calculates the difference of years between the two dates which not always gives the correct value for the age, since the day of the birthday may not have occurred in the current year.
Maybe this can be better achieved using UDFs...
Anybody out there has implemented something similar so far?
Thanks in advance

Remember that Cosmos DB doesn't have an actual datetime type - you'd have to convert your stored value to a datetime before doing your computation. In your example, you're comparing it to whatever string is in the DateOfBirth property (which you haven't shown any details about). Please edit to include specifics around this property, as well as specifics around issue(s) you're having with the result of cp_Age - essentially providing a [mcve] around your issue.

It turns out that CosmosDB functions accept a DateOnly as a parameter as well as an ISO 8601 formatted date, so, basing on an old SQL answer relating the same problem (Calculating age with SQL) I've managed to get the desired result using the available CosmosDB functions:
    {
        "name": "cp_Age",
        "query": "SELECT VALUE DateTimeDiff('YYYY', u.DateOfBirth, GetCurrentDateTime()) - IIF((DateTimePart('mm', u.DateOfBirth) > DateTimePart('mm', GetCurrentDateTime())) OR ((DateTimePart('mm', u.DateOfBirth) = DateTimePart('mm', GetCurrentDateTime())) AND ((DateTimePart('dd', u.DateOfBirth) > DateTimePart('dd', GetCurrentDateTime())))),1,0) FROM u"
    }

It's a quite long expression but it works perfectly.
